# RecyclerView Item EditText doesn't change default values after writing new values in it, using TextWatcher and ROOM database

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I have this issue: Im creating an app where a user adds a "Set" to a Exercise and when he clicks a button "+" it adds a new "Set" to the list of sets in the Activity. There are two edittext fields in the recyclerview item list: edittext_rep and edittext_weight , where you have to write down your reps and weight of your set and to save the values to room and when opening the activity again to show the values that you previously wrote. I have this code of my Activity:

```
public class Exercise extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView setAdd, exerciseName;
Button btnSetAdd;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
SetAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);

    setAdd = findViewById(R.id.textView_setAdd);
    exerciseName = findViewById(R.id.textView_exerciseName);
    btnSetAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAddSet);

    String selectedExerciseName = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXERCISE_NAME");
    exerciseName.setText(selectedExerciseName);

    initRecyclerView();
    loadSetList();
    loadSavedValues();

    btnSetAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int rep = 0;
            double weight = 0;
            int exerciseId = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXERCISE_ID", -1);

            addNewSet(rep, weight, exerciseId);
        }
    });
}

private void loadSavedValues() {
    AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    int exerciseId = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXERCISE_ID", -1);
    if (exerciseId != -1) {
        List<SetItem> setsForExercise = database.setDao().getSetsForExercise(exerciseId);
        recyclerViewAdapter.setSetList(setsForExercise);
        setStoredValues(setsForExercise);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        Log.e("ExerciseActivity", "No exercise ID found in the intent");
    }
}

private void setStoredValues(List<SetItem> setsForExercise) {
    for (SetItem setItem : setsForExercise) {
        setItem.setStoredRep(setItem.getRep());
        setItem.setStoredWeight(setItem.getWeight());
    }
}

private void loadSetList() {
    AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    int exerciseId = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXERCISE_ID", -1);
    if (exerciseId != -1) {
        // Fetch exercises associated with the selected workout ID
        List<SetItem> setsForExercise = database.setDao().getSetsForExercise(exerciseId);
        recyclerViewAdapter.setSetList(setsForExercise);
    } else {
        Log.e("WorkoutActivity", "No workout ID found in the intent");
    }
}

private void addNewSet(int rep, double weight, int exercise_id) {
    int exerciseId = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXERCISE_ID", -1);
    if (exerciseId != -1) {
        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        ExerciseItem exerciseItem = database.exerciseDao().getExerciseById(exerciseId);
        if (exerciseItem != null) {
            SetItem setItem = new SetItem();
            setItem.setExercise_id(exercise_id);
            setItem.setRep(rep);
            setItem.setWeight(weight);
            database.setDao().insertSetItem(setItem);
        }

    }
    recyclerViewAdapter.addSet();
}

public void initRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_sets);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new SetAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
}
```

And then i have this Adapter for the recyclerview :

```
public class SetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<SetItem> setList;

public void addSet() {
    setList.add(new SetItem());
    notifyItemInserted(setList.size() - 1);
}
public void setSetList(List<SetItem> setList){
    this.setList = setList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public List<SetItem> getSetList(){
    return setList;
}
public SetAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.setList = new ArrayList<>();
}
@NonNull
@Override
public SetAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_sets, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SetAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SetItem set = setList.get(position);
    holder.textView_setNumber.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
    holder.editText_rep.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            try {
                int reps = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                set.setRep(reps);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Handle invalid input if needed
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {
                int reps = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                set.setStoredRep(reps);
                Log.d("SetAdapter", "Stored Rep: " + set.getStoredRep()); // Log the stored rep

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Handle invalid input if needed
            }
        }
    });
    holder.editText_rep.setText(String.valueOf(set.getStoredRep()));
    Log.d("SetAdapter", "Stored Rep: " + set.getStoredRep());
    holder.editText_weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                double weight = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                set.setWeight(weight);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Handle invalid input if needed
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {
                double weight = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                set.setStoredWeight(weight);
                Log.d("SetAdapter", "Stored Weight: " + set.getStoredWeight()); // Log the stored weight

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Handle invalid input if needed
            }
        }
    });
    holder.editText_weight.setText(String.valueOf(set.getStoredWeight()));
    Log.d("SetAdapter", "Stored Weight: " + set.getStoredWeight());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return setList.size();
}
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textView_setNumber;
    EditText editText_rep, editText_weight;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        editText_rep = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText_rep);
        editText_weight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText_weight);
        textView_setNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_setNumber);


    }
}
```

This is the SetItem:

```
    @Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = ExerciseItem.class,
        parentColumns = "id",
        childColumns = "exercise_id",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class SetItem {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "exercise_rep")
    public int rep;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "exercise_weight")
    public double weight;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "exercise_id")
    public int exercise_id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "stored_rep")
    public int storedRep;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "stored_weight")
    public double storedWeight;

    public int getStoredRep() {
        return storedRep;
    }

    public double getStoredWeight() {
        return storedWeight;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getRep() {
        return rep;
    }
    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setExercise_id(int exercise_id) {
        this.exercise_id = exercise_id;
    }

    public void setStoredRep(int storedRep) {
        this.storedRep = storedRep;
    }

    public void setStoredWeight(double storedWeight) {
        this.storedWeight = storedWeight;
    }

    public void setRep(int rep) {
        this.rep = rep;
    }
    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public int getExercise_id(){
        return exercise_id;
    }
}
```

and this is the SetDao:

```
    @Dao
public interface SetDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM setitem WHERE exercise_id = :exerciseId")
    List<SetItem> getSetsForExercise(int exerciseId);
    @Insert
    void insertSetItem(SetItem... setItems);
    @Delete
    void delete(SetItem setItem);
}
```

So I have this Appdatabase.java too:

```
    @Database(entities = {WorkoutItem.class, ExerciseItem.class, SetItem.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract WorkoutDao workoutDao();
    public abstract ExerciseDao exerciseDao();
    public abstract SetDao setDao();

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "DB_NAME")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();

        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

WorkoutItem.java :

```
    @Entity
public class WorkoutItem {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "workout_name")
    public String workoutName;

    public String getWorkoutName() {
        return workoutName;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

WorkoutDao.java :

```
    @Dao
public interface WorkoutDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM workoutitem")
    List<WorkoutItem> getAllWorkoutItems();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM workoutitem WHERE id = :workoutId")
    WorkoutItem getWorkoutById(int workoutId);

    @Insert
    void insertWorkoutItem(WorkoutItem... workoutItems);
    @Delete
    void delete(WorkoutItem workoutItem);
}
```

ExerciseItem.java :

```
    @Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = WorkoutItem.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "workout_id",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class ExerciseItem {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "exercise_name")
    public String exerciseName;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "workout_id")
    public int workoutId;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getExerciseName() {
        return exerciseName;
    }

    public int getWorkoutId() {
        return workoutId;
    }
}
```

ExerciseDao.java :

```
    @Dao
public interface ExerciseDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM exerciseitem WHERE workout_id = :workoutId")
    List<ExerciseItem> getExercisesForWorkout(int workoutId);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM exerciseitem WHERE id = :exerciseId")
    ExerciseItem getExerciseById(int exerciseId);
    @Insert
    void insertExerciseItem(ExerciseItem... exerciseItems);
    @Delete
    void delete(ExerciseItem exerciseItem);

}
```

So when i open the activity the default values of edittext_rep and weight is 0, when i write any other value i see in the log that it changes the storedRep/storedWeight , but when i restart the activity it shows again the default ones - 0. I appreciate if you can help me resolve this. Have a nice day and thank you! :)

Comment: I dont see any Room. And functions like setStoredRep() are missing.

Comment: @blackapps i edit the post and placed the SetItem.java and the SetDao.

Comment: Which statement stores data in Room database?

Comment: @blackapps The interface SetDao is "Dao" and SetItem.java is a "Entity" of the database , i posted the Appdatabase.java aswell so you can look at the whole code. It saves the exercises for a workout by id for the workout and then opening the exercise's set list based on the id of the exercise, this works fine , the problem is when i change lets say the first set reps to "12" and then go out of the activity and then come back to it , the reps on the first set will be by default "0" and not the value that i put in.

Comment: @blackapps found the solution by myself, really got my head thinking about the problem whole week and the problem could be solved with ease , but it just got out of my mind haha! You can look down on the answer that i provided and thank you for your time :) Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: I've created Interface:

```
    public interface SetItemChangeListener {
    void onRepValueChanged(int position, int newValue);
    void onWeightValueChanged(int position, double newValue);
}
```

added it to the SetAdapter and changed the OnBindViewHolder abit :

```
    public class SetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<SetItem> setList;
    private SetItemChangeListener itemChangeListener;

    public void setItemChangeListener(SetItemChangeListener listener) {
        this.itemChangeListener = listener;
    }
    public void removeSetItem(SetItem setItem) {
        int position = setList.indexOf(setItem);
        if (position != -1) {
            setList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
    public void addSet() {
        setList.add(new SetItem());
        notifyItemInserted(setList.size() - 1);
    }
    public void setSetList(List<SetItem> setList){
        this.setList = setList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public List<SetItem> getSetList(){
        return setList;
    }
    public SetAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.setList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SetAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_sets, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SetAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SetItem set = setList.get(position);
        holder.textView_setNumber.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

        int storedRep = set.getStoredRep();
        double storedWeight = set.getStoredWeight();

        holder.editText_rep.setText(String.valueOf(storedRep));
        holder.editText_weight.setText(String.valueOf(storedWeight));

        holder.editText_rep.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                String newValueStr = holder.editText_rep.getText().toString();
                try {
                    int newValue = Integer.parseInt(newValueStr);
                    setList.get(position).setStoredRep(newValue);
                    itemChangeListener.onRepValueChanged(position, newValue);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // Handle invalid input if needed
                }
            }
        });

        holder.editText_weight.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                String newValueStr = holder.editText_weight.getText().toString();
                try {
                    double newValue = Double.parseDouble(newValueStr);
                    setList.get(position).setStoredWeight(newValue);
                    itemChangeListener.onWeightValueChanged(position, newValue);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return setList.size();
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView_setNumber;
        EditText editText_rep, editText_weight;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            editText_rep = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText_rep);
            editText_weight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText_weight);
            textView_setNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_setNumber);

        }
    }
}
```

Added an update method in the SetDao:

```
@Update
void updateSetItem(SetItem setItem);
```

and then in the Activity i implemented the interface and added these lines:

```
public class Exercise extends AppCompatActivity implements SetItemChangeListener
```

The onRepValue Changed and onWeightValueChanged:

```
@Override
public void onRepValueChanged(int position, int newValue) {
    List<SetItem> setList = recyclerViewAdapter.getSetList();
    if (setList != null && position >= 0 && position < setList.size()) {
        setList.get(position).setStoredRep(newValue);
        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        database.setDao().updateSetItem(setList.get(position));

 
    }
}

@Override
public void onWeightValueChanged(int position, double newValue) {
    List<SetItem> setList = recyclerViewAdapter.getSetList();
    if (setList != null && position >= 0 && position < setList.size()) {
        setList.get(position).setStoredWeight(newValue);
        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        database.setDao().updateSetItem(setList.get(position));

      
    }
}
```

Now it works as it saves the values from the EditText that I'm writing on edittext_rep and edittext_weight.